# codeigniter - Loading images, css, js, video, (web resources) into your html

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working in my first CodeIgniter project...

After building most of my PHP and start playing with the almost finished scrip I realized that all access to `application/views/` folder is denied by the `.htaccess`.

This is a huge problem for my file structure when I want to access page-specific JavaScript, Images or any web-resource folder. Since all my `views template` assumes that the file is used locally (That being `Page_name/images/cutedog.jpg`, in my code more precisely `<img src="{images}cutedog.jpg">`).

The solution that I found is modifying the .htacces so that it filters out all media files and it allows access to my application folder. But then by doing that I would reveal my file structure which I would rather avoid.

I know what I could just place my web resources outside my application folder and that would solve the problem. But for maintainability purposes I think it would be more logic to have everything as it is right now.

So my question is at follows... What work around would you suggests so that:
 - I can maintain my web resources at  `application/views/issue/WEB_PAGE/Web-resource-folder`
- keep my file structure hidden
- web-resources can be accessed

my .htaccess

```
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|jpg|pdf|avi|mpg|robots\.txt|png|pdf|favicon\.ico)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

My file structure:

```
-+ /application/
 |
 |-+ /Typical CI folders/        
 |-+ /view/
   |-+ /issue/
     |-+ /1/
       |-+ /page1/
         |-+ /img/
         |-+ /js/
         |-+ /video/
       |-+ /page2/
         |-+ /img/
         |-+ /js/
         |-+ /video/
```

Comment: You should never need to access the application directory directly. Your controllers, views, and routes should be handling all of that for you. Have you maybe misunderstood how CI works?

Comment: Javascript, and CSS resources can be placed in a public 'scripts' or 'CSS' directory, and then you only need to modify the core CI .htaccess to make sure it doesn't rewrite requests to those folders to index.php.

Comment: This is a bad design. Why do you think you can't achieve the same if you put resources outside application folder?

Comment: The only thing that I am really interested to decouple from the main scrip is the JS. Having page folder specific JS allows a simpler way to modify and read things. Specially when some of the people building it are less technical. I am trying to simplify "where things go" and readibility for some people that will be touching the system. Mainly because I had a custom MVC that allowed to do that. if i cant do that on CI its fine. but would rather try to keep the old system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write complicated rewrite rules for that which will tell .htaccess something like:

```
if url is blah/bloh/blih/WEB_PAGE/images/cutedog.jpg 
then fetch application/views/issue/WEB_PAGE/img/cutedlog.jpg
```

If you ask me that is going to become more and more cumbersome as you create more resources. Like you suggested you should place your web resources outside your application folder.

My CI Structure always looks like this:

```
/application
/resources
   /page1
      /img
      /js
      /video
   /page2
      /img
      /js
      /video
```